# How to replace all '\n' character after 'word' with 'comma' character

Tags: regex, rust

Trying to replace all the \n character after the word 'key2:' pattern with comma.

**Input String:**

```
key1:value1\nkey2:value2\nvalue22\nvalue222
```

**Expected:**

```
key1:value1\nkey2:value2,value22,value222
```

Tried:

```
r'key2:(\n*$)' replace with ','
```

any suggestions on how can i replace it using regex! from https://rustexp.lpil.uk/

Comment: Where are you trying this?  Does [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/yDnazi/1) help?

Comment: You can't do it with plain regex in Rust.

Comment: Iterate over the utf graphemes, and remember the last n graphemes, where n is the number of graphemes in your key. Compare the concatenation of the current grapheme and last n graphemes. If match, key is found; continue iteration without remembering graphemes and only check if current grapheme matches to-be-replaced grapheme, replacing with replacement grapheme if matched. O(n)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can easily be done with regex, so I'd propose a simpler way:

```
let mut s = String::from("key1:value1\nkey2:value2\nvalue22\nvalue222");
let expected = "key1:value1\nkey2:value2,value22,value222";

let key2 = "key2";
let substr_index = s.find(key2).unwrap() + key2.len();
let commas = s[substr_index..].replace("\n", ",");
s.replace_range(substr_index.., &commas);

assert_eq!(s, expected);
```